# Error executing SQL script; The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:'C:\\Users\\......\....cnf'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a script to import data into MySQL. When I tried, this error shown up. I have searched for a workaround but none is helping. I deleted all the related .cnf file in the said path after a few attempts on trying to run the script but it kept on creating a new one. I have no other means of importing the data besides running that script. Terribly sorry if I somehow really ask a silly question about this but I am new with SQL, stuck and need help on the matter. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Feels like an issue with the mysqlWorkbench client. Try to reboot your machine or maybe reinstall the client. Also look into a different client options like HeidiSQL.

Comment: I reverted back to [`8.0.20`](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/) and it works again

Comment: Please share more details, like the script you are running, the error message you are facing (in text form!) and your attempts to resolve the problem. Is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have the same error as you, I've manage to solve it on my end by following these steps:

1. Rather than doing "run sql script", do "open sql script"
2. After the script open, Execute all (the lightning btn beside the save icon)

Hope this will work for you too!

Comment: Even this may work it is not suitable for big sql scripts files.
Instead use 'Server' -> 'Data Import' while connected to the mysql server

Comment: This answer did not work for me because of the size of my script. @Kwaadpepper's answer did work, however.

Comment: Also is not working when you have linked scripts using SOURCE.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well and, like @Alexandre-St-Amant, the size of my script prohibited opening the script as @vika suggests.

Before noticing @Kwaadpepper's suggestion, I tried using connecting to my database through mysqlsh.exe, then used SOURCE <data_file>. This has the added benefit of allowing linked scripts using SOURCE, solving @Adrian-Moldovan's issue.

Of course, this does not use *mysql-workbench* to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My sql file was really big and I was not able to copy the contents or load the file. Instead, do this :

```
Server' -> 'Data Import
```

Dump the data from sql file from here. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my sql script.
You may try reinstall the client and workbench. You should follow one version of applications. After that actions my script has worked.

Comment: consider as comment instead of answer